# 502 Bad Gateway wheyn trying to access rails app deployed with dokku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, postgresql

I've been trying to deploy a rails app with Dokku following Steven's guide.

The app deployed successfully according to the logs on push. I created a postgres database, linked it to the app and ran migration. All these operations executed successfully.

When I try to visit the app, however, I get a 502 bad gateway error.

A part of my logs is shown below:

```js
:11:54 worker.1  | 2015-09-19T06:11:54+0000: [Worker(host:861baaccc2e0 pid:18)] Starting job worker
06:11:54 worker.1  | [Worker(host:861baaccc2e0 pid:18)] Error while reserving job:
06:11:54 worker.1  | Problem:
06:11:54 worker.1  |   No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'.
06:11:54 worker.1  | Summary:
06:11:54 worker.1  |   When attempting to create the new session, Mongoid could not find a session configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
06:11:54 worker.1  | Resolution:
06:11:54 worker.1  |   Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the sessions key that a configuration exists for 'default'. If you have set the configuration programatically, ensure that 'default' exists in the configuration hash.
06:11:54 worker.1  | 2015-09-19T06:11:54+0000: [Worker(host:861baaccc2e0 pid:18)] Error while reserving job:
06:11:54 worker.1  | Problem:
06:11:54 worker.1  |   No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'.
06:11:54 worker.1  | Summary:
06:11:54 worker.1  |   When attempting to create the new session, Mongoid could not find a session configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
06:11:54 worker.1  | Resolution:
06:11:54 worker.1  |   Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the sessions key that a configuration exists for 'default'. If you have set the configuration programatically, ensure that 'default' exists in the configuration hash.
06:11:54 web.1     | [2015-09-19 06:11:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
06:11:54 web.1     | [2015-09-19 06:11:54] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
06:11:54 web.1     | [2015-09-19 06:11:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=20 port=5200
06:11:54 console.1 | exited with code 0
06:11:54 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
06:11:54 rake.1    | rake aborted!
06:11:54 worker.1  | [Worker(host:861baaccc2e0 pid:18)] Exiting...
06:11:54 worker.1  | 2015-09-19T06:11:54+0000: [Worker(host:861baaccc2e0 pid:18)] Exiting...
06:11:54 rake.1    | SignalException: SIGTERM
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `block in eager_load!'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `each_value'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `eager_load!'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:34:in `eager_load!'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view.rb:87:in `eager_load!'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
06:11:54 rake.1    | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
```

My nginx error logs show:

```
2015/09/19 06:44:14 [error] 5421#0: *140 connect() failed (113: No  
route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 197.253.32.226, 
server: lycent.bamsonline.org
```

Though I didn't make any reference to MongoDB in my app, I tried adding `gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.0'` to my gem file and re-running migrations.

No references and tutorials I'm seeing online make any mention of MongoDB or mongoid.yml so I don't know if its mongo (or lack thereof) that is causing the issue, or something  else entirely.

A copy of my gem file is shown below:

```js
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'delayed_job_mongoid'

gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem "geocoder"

gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.0'
gem "activemodel"
gem 'gravtastic'

gem "tzinfo"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem "pry"
  gem "pry-nav"
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'

  gem 'spring'
end


group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: It certainly looks like something in your app is trying to use mongo - figuring out what should be your first task (for example do you have any gems that depend on mongo?)

Comment: At first, I was receiving a `delayed_jobs` error. When I looked that issue up, I was advised to add it to my gem file. Mongo db started showing up in the logs immediately after that. I'd paste a copy of my gem file as an edit now.

Comment: You don't need both delayed_job_active_record and delayed_job_mongoid. Just the active record one will do (and then remove mongoid too)

Comment: Okay. I've removed the delayed_job_mongoid. Now I'm having a different error stack on logs but still the same 502 error

Comment: You're going to want to paste the new stacktrace, otherwise we won't be able to figure out why your application won't start.

Comment: @JoseDiaz-Gonzalez I have been struggling with this since Saturday. I found out it kept trying to run my tests. So I put the condition at the top. Now I'm having even more cryptic logs. Lemme paste it.

Comment: Note: You'll probably get faster answers to your problem on our IRC channel (the maintainers idle there pretty often during evening hours EST/PST)